# xrdp with Win7Pro Remote Desktop not working

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

Installed xrdp on ubuntu 12.04 and it's enabled.  Logging in from Win7Pro, I get connected but no icons or taskbar show up; only the wallpaper is visible on the Win7 remote computer. Neither the left or right clicks do anything over the remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proper shell to be used with xrdp otherwhise you will see just wallpaper.
Hint: Unity does not work with XRDP but Unity 2D does!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but we thought would be nice to provide a final answer for such topic even if Ubuntu 12.04 is becoming obsolete....

You can find detailed instructions at [this location](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=2879)

- step 1 - Install xrdp
- Step 2 - Login locally on the UBuntu machine and edit the .xsession file and specify that you want to use the unity 2d interface (i.e.  echo gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d >~/.xsession

And you should be good to go

Till next time